# xpath: How to write conditional xpaths?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I am trying to extract price information from following two pages:

http://jujumarts.com/mobiles-accessories-smartphones-wildfire-sdarkgrey-p-551.html
http://jujumarts.com/computers-accessories-transcend-500gb-portable-storejet-25d2-p-2616.html

```
xpath1 = //span[@class='productSpecialPrice']//text()
xpath2 = //div[@class='proDetPrice']//text()
```

As of now I have written python code, which returns the result of xpath1 if it is successful otherwise executes the second one. I have a feeling that it is possible to implement this logic in xpath alone, can someone tell me how?

Comment: I am dealing with hundreds of websites here and handling multiple xpaths for every portal in order to be able to use try/except is seemingly clumsy. Apparently XPath 2.0 is very much capable of doing this.

Answer (score 4):

Use `|` to indicate `union`:

```
xpath3 = "//span[@class='productSpecialPrice']//text()|//div[@class='proDetPrice']//text()"
```

This is not exactly what you asked for, but I think it could be incorporated in a workable solution.

---

From [the XPath (version 1.0) specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-sets):

> The | operator computes the union of its operands, which must be
>   node-sets.

---

For example,

```
import lxml.html as LH

urls = [
    'http://jujumarts.com/mobiles-accessories-smartphones-wildfire-sdarkgrey-p-551.html',
    'http://jujumarts.com/computers-accessories-transcend-500gb-portable-storejet-25d2-p-2616.html'
    ]

xpaths = [
    "//span[@class='productSpecialPrice']//text()",
    "//div[@class='proDetPrice']//text()",
    "//span[@class='productSpecialPrice']//text()|//div[@class='proDetPrice']//text()"
    ]
for url in urls:
    doc = LH.parse(url)
    for xpath in xpaths:
        print(doc.xpath(xpath))
    print
```

yields

```
['Rs.11,800.00']
['Rs.13,299.00', 'Rs.11,800.00']
['Rs.13,299.00', 'Rs.11,800.00']

[]
['Rs.7,000.00']
['Rs.7,000.00']
```

---

Another way to get at the information you want is

```
"//*[@class='productSpecialPrice' or @class='proDetPrice']//text()"
```

Comment: @root: Could you elaborate? What is the problem?

Comment: You can't say "use `|` to indicate `or`" when `|` actually indicates something somewhat different...as OP put it: `which returns the result of xpath1 if it is successful otherwise executes the second one`

Comment: @root: While that is true, I think the OP could just take the min of the prices returned, since hopefully the "SpecialPrice" will always be less than the regular price.

Comment: thats what I meant with the "however it may be suitable for what the OP is doing" part. picking on the wording more or less. Also, I don't want to be annoying, but have you tested the second one, because I am not sure if it would work :)

Comment: @root: Thanks for the comments. Also, thanks for the heads-up -- the last suggestion was missing a quotation mark. It is tested now and returns the same result as the first suggestion.

Comment: I think this is likely the best solution using `xpath` & `lxml` (unless *Dimitre Novatchev* comes along) :)